# Get picture field from Logged User in Play-Authenticate

Tags: playframework, play-authenticate

I'm using Play-Authenticate to enable users to login using Google account. Login is working fine. Now, I want to show the profile picture of logged in user.

I see that there is a 'picture' field in the provider.
com.feth.play.module.pa.providers.oauth2.google.GoogleAuthUser

How can I access this field in my controller so that I can show the picture in my views?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use instanceof to check if the [AuthUser](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/code/app/com/feth/play/module/pa/user/AuthUser.java) implements [com.feth.play.module.pa.user.PicturedIdentity](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/blob/master/code/app/com/feth/play/module/pa/user/PicturedIdentity.java), as GoogleAuthUser does.  You can then cast the AuthUser to a PicturedIdentity and invoke getPicture() on it.